# Open docker daemon to outside users command error

Tags: docker

I want to open my Docker server up for others to access, before the attempt to do so, I shut the current daemon down.

```
$ sudo service docker stop
```

Once the Docker daemon has been stopped, I tried to restart it manually and open it
up to outside users with the following command.

```
$ sudo docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375
```

What I get is

[image]

I tried with -d instead of daemon, still the same.
My current docker version is **Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962**

Comment: The command to launch docker daemon is `dockerd`. Moreover, consider configuring the daemon correctly in systemd (e.g. drop-in to set somewhere in /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/) for your modifications to survive reboot.

Comment: Also consider the implications of being able to run `DOCKER_HOST=tcp://10.20.30.40:2375 docker run -v /:/host busybox cat /host/etc/shadow` and similar things — this is a really easy way to get your machine rooted.